# How to append large content of data?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I need to append the large content of data(50Kb to 60Kb) after ajax post. When I'm do this it will take 10 to 12s and the browser has been hanged. So I tried to load that page with multiple asynchronous ajax request. But now also get some struggle(browser struck, click event not working) at the time of append the data. After the append process it'll working fine. Can anyone give me a suggestion to solve this problem?

Comment: Append a bit, fire a callback (using `setTimeout`) to append the next bit

Comment: Dont create element with ajax going on. Maybe you can send ajax requests one by one.

Comment: Do you really need to display all this huge amount of data all at once? Sounds like not ideal from UX perspective.

Comment: how about some code, how you appending it...

Comment: Try adding to an invisible div and finally show it. `$('#div').hide(); // append here $('#div').html('large data'); $('#div').show();`

Comment: I need to load 10 contents but show single content based on user selection. Remaining things are should be hidden state. Now i do that(explained in question) but it get more time.

Comment: Issue has been fixed by passing object in json and then done my work in Script side.